# Cross domain issue

Tags: soap, site.com, ajax

I am trying to access SOAP API from site.com page through AJAX call. In browser it is showing error like 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource...' . How can I solve this? How can I solve the cross domain accessing issue?

Comment: Have you activated clickjack updates in your org?

Comment: First of all are you using site.com or force.com sites?

Answer (score -2):

I've no idea what you are trying to do or call but I can tell you that you can't configure the Cross Origin Resource Sharing configuration on the Salesforce side (which is related to the error that you're getting).  It is possible to deploy a server to Heroku where the Cross Origin Resource Sharing configuration can be modified.